# Не создается файл в java

Tags: java, ubuntu, файлы, netbeans, io

Создаю файл таким вот кодом. Но, как ни стараюсь, не получается создать файл, хотя выполняется код без ошибок.

```
    try{
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("path --- ");
        String path = read.next();
        System.out.print("file name --- ");
        String file = read.next();
        File my = new File(path +"/"+ file);
        read.close();
    }catch(IOError exception){
        System.err.println("Fail");
        Files();
    }
}
```

Comment: так вы и не создаете файл!

Comment: В какой строке, по-вашему, должен создаваться файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File my = new File(path +"/"+ file);
my.createNewFile();
read.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так я решил свою проблему:

```
static void Files(){
 Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Path ----   ");
    String path = read.next();
    System.out.print("Name of file ----  ");
    String filename = read.next();
    File my = new File(path);
    read.close();
    if(!my.exists()){
        my.mkdir();
        try{
        File my1 = new File(path+"/"+filename);
        my1.createNewFile();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("There are some mistakes in your path 
        or filename. Try again");
        Files();
        }
    }else{
        try{
        File my1 = new File(path +"/"+filename);
        my1.createNewFile();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("There are some mistakes in your path or filename. Try again");
            Files();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/")
Path file = Files.createFile(path, null);
```